# Ising model as quantum model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, ising-model, spin-statistics

I've read in a few papers things that use the fact that the $2D$ Ising model can be interpreted as a $1+1$ quantum spin model. I haven't been able to find this description and would like to read about it. Could anyone recommend a book with this description?

Comment: I also like this analogy, e.g. it seems that we could realize Wick-rotated quantum computers in Ising-like systems: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/526439/wick-rotated-quantum-computers-e-g-to-be-realized-with-ising-like-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question, "Ising model as quantum model?", really opens a Pandora's box. Anyway, yes, in general, an $N\text{-dimensional}$ quantum (Ising) model can be mapped to an $N+1$ classical (Ising) model.

For a general start, maybe you could refer this book:

- ["Quantum Phase Transitions in Transverse Field Spin Models"](https://books.google.com/books/about/Quantum_Phase_Transitions_in_Transverse.html?id=2mrXCQAAQBAJ), by A. Dutta *et al.* (CUP).

You will find your questions addressed in the first chapter.

Also, and this is a bit of a spoiler alert if you want to figure it out by yourself, but the extra dimension in the classical case is *time*. It is best understood using the path integral formalism.